# Close VBS script if another task is closed

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm trying to build a basic installer with background music using a mix of VBS and a batch file.

I have a piece of code at the beginning of my script which is supposed to play a song while the installer does its thing. The problem is that if the installer is force-closed the VBS script continues to play the music.

Here is the code in question:

```
7za.exe x INSTALL\MUSIC -oINSTALL\MUSIC -r -y >NUL
set file=INSTALL\MUSIC\MUSIC.mp3
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
    start /min sound.vbs
```

Basically I need a way of letting the VBS script know if the `install.bat` file has been force closed or not. I assume I would use some form of `if` function, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing it.

Comment: Why not use CSCRIPT /? to help you along with this?  You should be able to sort out what you need for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code similar to what is on this blog post to see if the batch file is still running:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/06/01/how-can-i-find-the-process-id-associated-with-a-batch-file.aspx

You can edit the WMI query to specifically find your batch command process instead of having to loop through them.  The best way to accomplish this would be to create a function that runs the WMI query and returns True or False.  Call the function in your `do while` loop, and if it doesn't find your batch file running then `wscript.quit`.

Based on the fact that you are creating a VBScript by echoing out of a batch file, this will probably take you a while to get figured out.  Instead of creating the VBScript from the batch file, I would recommend creating the VBScript separately, and then call it with the necessary parameters.  If you don't know how to handle parameters, I would recommend that you learn that now as it will make your life easier if you're going to be doing stuff like this.